How to target object image to style it with CSS?
I have an array of 6 objects which are 6 images. I have rendered those images in a HTML table through JS code. Now I would like to target and style only ONE of them. Width, height, and so on.
How to do that in the most simple way as possible?
I tried to write a style key in the object with CSS code. Did not work.
I tried to getElementbyId on the specific img but it did not work either.
I have checked on other topics but what I've read, so far was really for complicated for what I want to do. I just want to change the size of ONE image.


const products = [{
    "id": 1,
    "image": "https://via.placeholder.com/50",
    "name": "Orient Vita Pro 28\"",
    "price": "284.00",
    "inventory": 4,
    "productCode": "K203"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "image": "https://via.placeholder.com/50",
    "name": "Orient S-400 26\"",
    "price": "198.00",
    "inventory": 14,
    "productCode": "K433"

  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "image": "https://via.placeholder.com/50",
    "name": "Bullet Bora 20\"",
    "price": "350.00",
    "inventory": 7,
    "productCode": "K012"
  },
  {
    "id": 4,
    "image": "https://via.placeholder.com/50",
    "name": "Feder handmade",
    "price": "790.00",
    "inventory": 5,
    "productCode": "G0127"
  },
  {
    "id": 5,
    "image": "https://via.placeholder.com/50",
    "name": "Ibanez G120",
    "price": "430.00",
    "inventory": 2,
    "productCode": "G1233"
  },
  {
    "id": 6,
    "image": "https://via.placeholder.com/50",
    "name": "Feder Blues edition",
    "width": "1000",
    "price": "650.00",
    "inventory": 6,
    "productCode": "G4478"
  }
];

const placeholder = document.querySelector("#data-output");
let out = "";

for (let product of products) {
  out += `
            <tr>
                <td> <img src='${product.image}'> </td>
                <td>${product.name}</td>
                <td>${product.price}</td>
                <td>${product.inventory}</td>
                <td>${product.productCode}</td>
            </tr>
        `;
}

placeholder.innerHTML = out;
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Image</th>
      <th>Product name</th>
      <th>Price</th>
      <th>inventory</th>
      <th>Product code</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  
  <tbody id="data-output">
  </tbody>
</table>




why you don't add a class to that image?

"style only ONE of them" is it always a consistent one? And are those styles always the same, or variable depending on the data in the JSON?

I have reduced your code to a simple demo. Please revise further as needed.

If you can't add unique identifiers to the elements, then you may be able to leverage the :nth-child() CSS pseudo-selector

You do not style JSON, or JavaScript objects for that matter. You style HTML. The code shared here shows no indication of which image you wish to style.

I would like to add a class to a specific image but i can't figure out how? Please tell me i you know.

I just would like to know how to target ONE image with CSS so i can style it the way  i want.

You attempted an edit that would've broken the demo. I'm not sure why, but if you're abandoning the question you should delete it.

the code i wrote with 'const products =' does not work a Json file. I needed to delete the 'const products =' (see print img attached)

You weren't clear about why a style property wouldn't work. Seems like it would.


const products = [{
    "id": 1,
    "image": "https://via.placeholder.com/50",
    "name": "Orient Vita Pro 28\"",
    "price": "284.00",
    "inventory": 4,
    "productCode": "K203"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "image": "https://via.placeholder.com/50",
    "name": "Orient S-400 26\"",
    "price": "198.00",
    "inventory": 14,
    "productCode": "K433",
    "styles": { // <----------------------------------- HERE
      width: "25px",
      border: "2px solid orange"
    }
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "image": "https://via.placeholder.com/50",
    "name": "Bullet Bora 20\"",
    "price": "350.00",
    "inventory": 7,
    "productCode": "K012"
  },
  {
    "id": 4,
    "image": "https://via.placeholder.com/50",
    "name": "Feder handmade",
    "price": "790.00",
    "inventory": 5,
    "productCode": "G0127"
  },
  {
    "id": 5,
    "image": "https://via.placeholder.com/50",
    "name": "Ibanez G120",
    "price": "430.00",
    "inventory": 2,
    "productCode": "G1233"
  },
  {
    "id": 6,
    "image": "https://via.placeholder.com/50",
    "name": "Feder Blues edition",
    "width": "1000",
    "price": "650.00",
    "inventory": 6,
    "productCode": "G4478"
  }
];

const placeholder = document.querySelector("#data-output");
let out = "";

products.forEach(product => {
  let styleStr = '';

  if (product.styles) {
    Object.entries(product.styles).forEach(([key, value]) => {
      styleStr += key + ': ' + value + '; '
    });
  }

  out += `
            <tr>
                <td> <img src='${product.image}' style='${styleStr}'> </td>
                <td>${product.name}</td>
                <td>${product.price}</td>
                <td>${product.inventory}</td>
                <td>${product.productCode}</td>
            </tr>
        `;
});

placeholder.innerHTML = out;
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Image</th>
      <th>Product name</th>
      <th>Price</th>
      <th>inventory</th>
      <th>Product code</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody id="data-output">
  </tbody>
</table>




Firstly, the code I wrote with 'const products =' does not work in a Json file. I need to delete the 'const products =' (see print img attached)[Json file][1], which is why I deleted it.
Sorry about that.
Second, as you can see, the style property you add with the 'width' and 'border' attributes does not work either.
So my problem is not solved, unfortunately.
[1]: https://i.sstatic.net/XIJhmRjc.jpg
To answer the other comments,
I would like to add a class to a specific image but I can't figure out how? Please let me know if you're able to do that.
I just would like to know how to target ONE image with CSS so I can style it the way I want. Does not matter which image.
I have tried to use the img:nth-child() CSS pseudo-selector but it would target several img, and I only want to target one image.
Please let me know if you come up with something.

your attempts should not get posted as an answer, and the information provided should be included in the main question.
